# Populate drop down list from Oracle table

Tags: php, html, oracle

I have to populate drop down list from an oracle table I have used following code but it gives an empty drop down list.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<body>


 <p style="font-size:35px;"><b>History Trades</b></p>


 <form action="dat.php" method="post">
 Select Instrument :<select name="instument">

 <?php 
 $conn = oci_connect("cse", "mahesh123", "XE"); 
 $sql = 'SELECT symbol FROM symbols'; 
 $stid = oci_parse($conn, $sql); 
 $success = oci_execute($stid); 
 while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_RETURN_NULLS+OCI_ASSOC))  
 { 
 echo "<option value=\"countryname1\">" . $row['symbol'] . "</option>"; 
 } 
?>       
</select> 



 Start Date:
 <input type="date" name="bday1" >
 End Date:
 <input type="date" name="bday2" ><br><br>


 <input type="image" src="sub.jpg" alt="Submit" width="100" height="48">  


  </form>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Please help me with this, I need to do it in php code. please help me in the areas where I have the issue in the given code.

Comment: What values to put and what variable name holds it?

Comment: just text values

Comment: Make sure `$row['symbol']` has value. If none, check if you're fetching from the right db column which is currently `symbol`.

Comment: You are also using `'countryname1'` as value for each option. You may need fix that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Field names are upper case by default in Oracle, and array keys are case-sensitive in PHP, so:

```
echo "<option value=\"countryname1\">" . $row['SYMBOL'] . "</option>";
```

Also, turn on error output in your PHP development environment.  That would have shown a `Notice: Undefined index: symbol in ...` message, allowing you to fix the problem quite quickly.

Comment: @user1793864 Any response to this answer? Did it solve your problem?